# Java Constants inheritance

Tags: java

I noticed I can do:

```
public class Message {

    public static final int MIN_BYTES = 5;
}
```

...and set this class as parent of another and set the same constant with another value like:

```
public class Ack extends Message {

    public static final int MIN_BYTES = 1;
}
```

Since compiler does not complaing, this lead me to the questions above:

1. Are these variables really the same?
2. I would say it gets the most specific, so in that case from the Ack class. Is that true?
3. Constants cannot have their value changed (it is final), so if the question 1 is true, how is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: These are two separated static fields, existing individually. You cannot override static members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No.  `Ack.MIN_BYTES` and `Message.MIN_BYTES` have no relationship to each other.
2. It's not clear what you're asking -- *what* gets the most specific?  `a.MIN_VALUE` depends on the *static* type of `a` -- if you write `Message a = new Ack()`, then `a.MIN_VALUE` will give you `Message.MIN_BYTES = 5`.  If you write `Ack a = new Ack()`, then `a.MIN_VALUE` will give you `Ack.MIN_BYTES = 1`.
3. Not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The second does not overwrite the first. It just hides it within `Ack`. **ALL** class members declared `public static final` can be accessed using `[fullpackagename].[classname].[variablename]`